# Installation of Microsoft Azure Pack on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: azure, installation

I'm trying to install the Microsoft Azure Pack  on a offline Windows 2012 R2 Server in our Company. Whe using the Webplatform Installer (from a client with Internet-Access) we were not able to find the packages to install. I used this link as a guide:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/07/22/step-by-step-installing-microsoft-azure-pack-for-windows-server/

At Step 4.2 I can't find the "Azure Pack: Portal and API Express" (the other Packs like Websites V2 etc. are also missing)

Is it possible to install this packet without the Web-Platform-Installer?

Does somebody know wether Azure is still supported by Microsoft and/or downloadable?

Thanks!